# How to convert iOS function to Ruby. Generating hmac-sha1 hash?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode

I would like to know how to generate an hmac-sha1 hash in ruby, in the same way it is generated in iOS. So far the hash from iOS does not match the one generated via Ruby.
This is to authenticate an user that provides username and password via an iOS app and via a web app.

So far I have:

**iOS Code**

```
+ (NSString *)hmacsha1:(NSString *)text key:(NSString *)secret {
    NSData *secretData = [secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *clearTextData = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned char result[20];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, [secretData bytes], [secretData length], [clearTextData bytes], [clearTextData length], result);

    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", result[i]];
    return output;
}
```

**Ruby Code**

```
  def self.signature(base_string, consumer_secret=HOST_KEY)
    require "base64"
    digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1')
    hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, consumer_secret, base_string)
    hmac = Base64.encode64(hmac)
    xx_log("SIGNATURE", hmac)
    return hmac
  end
```

**Calling the Function in Ruby**

```
string_for_hash = params[:username].to_s.downcase + ' ' + params[:password].to_s
params[:hash] = ApiKey.signature(string_for_hash)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

The result simply should match a generic hmac sha1 conversion. No need to translate the iOS code.

```
def hmac_sha1(data, secret=HOST_KEY)
    require 'base64'
    require 'cgi'
    require 'openssl'
    hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'), secret.encode("ASCII"), data.encode("ASCII"))
    return hmac
end
```